# Latex png image embedding code producing no viewable output in pdf form

Tags: graphics, pdf, png

i have been trying to embed a png image in latex. i have compiled the document but when i press to view the pdf document there is no output of the image in the pdf viewer. here is the code i used;

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,natwidth=3,natheight=4]{3d_scatter.png}
\end{figure}
```

this code does not produce any image in the pdf viewer but i do see the rest of the document. i have tried playing with the values but it makes no difference, but i also don't get back any errors when i compile it. any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. For your problem is not guilty showed code fragment (well, it is a bit strange, but it works). We can help you only, if you extend your code fragment into small but complete document, which we cat test as its and which if course reproduce your problem. Can you see your image in some images  viewer?

Comment: Try to remove ,natwidth=3,natheight=4.

Comment: Now I'm wondering, from where exactly do you have that you should be using `natwidth` and `natheight`?

Comment: @oldenios that should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: natwidth and natheight is wrong, but they should actually give an error. It looks as if the fix hasn't been released yet ;-(. See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/21. We will look at it.